# Can't get this simple temporary table code to work

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables

When the middle two lines are taken out, the blank output appears properly (single column)!

```
CREATE TABLE #ProductNames (ProductName varchar(40));

INSERT INTO #ProductNames
SELECT p.ProductName FROM DBO.PRODUCTS AS p;

SELECT * FROM #ProductNames;
```

[image: Screenshot of error while running the whole thing]

Here is how the DBO.PRODUCTS look like:

[image: Screenshot of how the main data table looks like]

Also, the question carries a strange NOTE/suggestion in the last line that reads: << Note: you need to specify the Products table as Products, not dbo.Products. >>

This is the outcome following that note! -
[[image: Following the 'Note' in the Instructions][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deM5C.png)

Comment: Well does `DBO.PRODUCTS` actually have any data in it?

Comment: Yup it has, uploading a screenshot of that too in my main post

Comment: This shouldn't be happening AFAIK.  I would suggest doing this directly from SQL Server Management Studio.  I suspect that there is something kinky going on with the website you are using.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the tips @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: You've specified the products table as `dbo.products`; the last note says not to do that; maybe that's the issue (not a SQL problem; but maybe a limitation of this site).

Comment: You should do exactly as stated: `INSERT INTO #ProductNames
SELECT p.ProductName FROM PRODUCTS.PRODUCTS AS p;` My guesses are `VIEW or ROW LEVEL SECURITY` to not mess up with tables from dbo schema by multiple users.

Comment: @JohnLBevan- that last line in the question makes so sense at all. I have tried it out actually following the strange instructions, sadly same outcome! Anyways, I think it is a datacamp bug. I have reported the issue to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm aware this is well over 12 months after the fact, but I'm currently doing the same course the OP posted the question from, this answer has just been accepted by DataCamp as correct:

```
CREATE TABLE #ProductNames(ProductName varchar(40))

INSERT INTO #ProductNames 
SELECT ProductName FROM Products

SELECT * FROM  #ProductNames
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a SELECT INTO statement like so:

```
SELECT ProductName 
INTO #ProductNames
FROM DBO.PRODUCTS;

SELECT * 
FROM #ProductNames;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the site has created a schema for you.

It just so happens that there is a [Products] table in the [dbo] schema.

You need to work with [Products], not [dbo].[Products]. When resolving an unqualified object name, such as [Products], SQL Server will first look for the object within your default schema. Most likely, your default schema is the one that the site has created for you.